# Haxe cross-compiling for Mac using Windows

Tags: windows, macos, cross-compiling, haxe

I am using Haxe to develop a simple console application (say, a md5sum equivalent). No libraries, OS-specific functions, etc, just stdin/stdout and files.

Can I build a Mac binary (not AIR, not Flash) while using Windows as my development environment?

Is it even possible?

Also, it would be nice to build linux ELF too, but not required as I have a Linux VM but don't have a Mac.

**UPDATE: Found [xCross](http://code.google.com/p/xcross/wiki/help)**, trying now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [xCross](http://code.google.com/p/xcross/wiki/help) thingy (used to create haxe installer, IIRC) seems to do the job nicely. Though binaries are a bit outdated, so it's wise to build it yourself at least once ;)

UPD: it works. But yes, you need a Mac once to rebuild it from source.

Comment: Seems to be a really useful library, I'll have to do similar cross compiling, I'll try it.